# Not able to delete an account on a login page made using flask

Tags: python, flask, mysql-python

I'm trying to make a simple login page using python flask and MySQL. The webpage itself is being made using html, bootstrap 4 and css. I followed a tutorial to make the login page but now I want to add a way to delete an account.

This is a profile page which is visible after you login(it shows your username, password and email). The database table(called accounts) has a primary key id. The part in /// is the code I'm trying to add for creating a delete button. **Please help me fix my delete account button**.

```
@app.route('/pythonlogin/profile', methods = ['GET'])
def profile():
    # Check if user is loggedin
    if 'loggedin' in session:
        # We need all the account info for the user so we can display it on the profile page
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = %s', (session['id'],))
        account = cursor.fetchone()
        # Show the profile page with account info
        return render_template('profile.html', account=account)
    # User is not loggedin redirect to login page
    ///if request.method == 'GET':

        id = session['id']
        mycursor = mysql.cursor()
        sql = ('DELETE from accounts WHERE id = 4;')
        # return redirect(url_for('logout)')
        mycursor.execute(sql)
        mysql.connection.commit()///


    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

The following is the html part called profile.html.

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block title %}Profile{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Profile Page</h2>
<div>
    <p>Your account details are below:</p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td>{{ account['username'] }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td>{{ account['password'] }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td>{{ account['email'] }}</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <form action="{{ url_for('logout') }}">
            <td>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Account</button>
            </td>
            </form>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I really need help with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the provided code I can see some mistakes (logical)

1. If use logged in, code after `return render_template('profile.html', account=account)`
    will not be executed
2. And another problem is that you are creating the URL to logout instead of the profile page `<form action="{{ url_for('logout') }}">`

And better to do the form with POST method.

Comment: I want the page to logout when the person's account is deleted. How do I do that?

Comment: It is possible to redirect user to home page, as he will not have any session, he will be considered as non logged user

Comment: Does that mean I don't have to redirect the user to any page and he will be redirected to the home page automatically or do I have to redirect to home page?

Comment: You have to do it yourself. Steps: delete user, remove session parameter, redirect to home page. The last step may be different, it mostly depends on the logic of the applciation

Comment: Thank you so much for those steps. I was able to successfully create by delete button my resolving the problems one step at a time using the steps you provided.